# Windows phone7 ListPicker

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

In my windows phone7 application I have to Use a control something similar to a dropdown list control. So I came across the ListPicker that come up with the WP7 toolkit assembly.

The problem I've got is, it overlaps with the other elements in the page. Following is a screenshot of the interface.

[image]

When I click the ListPicker, it expands the list and allow me to select one item out of that. But when I select an item it clicks the button which appears just below to that. I can do `ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"` but it will go for full screen mode and since the list picker has only 3 items its not the way I want.

Does anyone know any way that I can let the ListPicker expand and select one out of it without occurring the button click which resides below it.

**Edits**

I have installed `WP7 Tool kit for Silverlight` and added the dll in to the project as a reference `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit`

XAML--->

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"


<toolkit:ListPicker Name="listPicker1"/>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks Paul. I just added the XAML part. in the page load provide the ItemSource for ListPiclker as a list(List<string> country)[listPicker1.ItemsSource = country;]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you are using a Canvas to layout your controls. If you use a Grid, then the ListPicker will work nicely (automatically shift the controls below it while the list is expanded) with any other controls that you place underneath :-

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="MyListPicker"
                            Grid.Row="0">
            <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="item1" />
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="item2" />
                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="item3" />
            </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
        <Button x:Name="MyButton"
                Content="Check availability"
                Click="MyButton_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
```